# Vue: Can't set the computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I need some help with computed properties and ajax in vue.

"filterFactories" is a list of factories.
The computed property "filterFactories" creates this list of factories.

Now, I want a new feature:
I have a button for an ajax request which get some new factories.
I want set the computed property "filterFactories" after an ajax request.
Unfortunately nothing happens.
it makes no difference:
1. this.filterFactories = response;
  or
2. window.filterFactories = response;
In both cases - nothing happened

Is it possible to update the "filterFactories" after the successfull ajax request?

I have added a larger code snipped

```html
<div id="app">

 <div id="filter">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Factory</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" v-model="searchFactory">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" v-on:click="clearSearchFactory">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
       </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <Multiselect 
     v-model="selectedCapabilities" 
     :options="allCapabilities"
     label="name"
     placeholder= "Select capabilities"
     track-by="id"
     :multiple="true"
    ></Multiselect>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <Multiselect 
     v-model="selectedCountries" 
     :options="allCountries"
     label="name"
     placeholder= "Select countries"
     track-by="code"
     :multiple="true"
    ></Multiselect>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!--Modal-->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   <h4 class="modal-title">{{this.clickedCapability.name}}</h4>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <!--......-->
   </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"  @click="filterProperties">OK</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="row" style="height: 35px; margin: 10px">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" v-for="cap in selectedCapabilities" @click="modalCapClicked(cap)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> {{ cap.name }} <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></button>
 </div>
 
 <!--Factories-->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id="myCard-wrapper" v-for="factory in this.filterFactories">
   <!--a list of factories-->
  </div>
 </div>

 
 
</div>

<script>


  window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
 components: {
  Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
   },
     data() {
   return {
  //Capabilities
  allCapabilities: [],      // alle Capabilities aus der Konfiguration die über das Json übermittelt wurden
  selectedCapabilities: [],      // selektierte Capabilities
  clickedCapability: '',      // im Modalfenster geöffnete Capability

  //Countries
  selectedCountries: [],       // selektierte Countries 
  allCountries: [],       // alle Countries aus der Json
  
  //Factories    
  searchFactory: '',       // Freitext Suchfeld für Fabriken
  factories: []        // angezeigte Fabriken
   }
 }, 
 computed:{
  /* Filtert die Fabriken anhand der Kriterien: Suche-Input, Capabilities, Countries */
  filterFactories: function(){
   var filteredFactories = [];
   
   var allFilter = [];
   allFilter.push(this.filterFactoriesBySearchInput());
   allFilter.push(this.filterFactoriesByCaps());
   allFilter.push(this.filterFactoriesByCountries());
   
   filteredFactories = allFilter.shift().filter(function(v) {
    return allFilter.every(function(a) {
     return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
    });
   });
   
   return filteredFactories;
  }
 },
 methods: {
  /* Filtert anhand der Suchfeld-Eingabe */
  filterFactoriesBySearchInput(){
   /*filter an return a new list of factories*/
  },
  /* Filtert anhand der Capabilities */
  filterFactoriesByCaps(){
   /*filter an return a new list of factories*/
  },
  /* Filtert anhand der Countries */
  filterFactoriesByCountries(){ 
   /*filter an return a new list of factories*/
  },
  /* Setzt die aktuell im Modal-Fenster geöffnete Capability */
  modalCapClicked(cap){
   this.clickedCapability = cap;    
  }
  filterProperties(){ 

   axios.post('.....................................')
   .then(function (response) {
    
    this.factories = response.data.factoriesJson;
    
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
   });
  },
  clearSearchFactory(){
   this.searchFactory = [];
  }
 },
 beforeMount(){
  axios.get('.........').then(response => {
    this.factories = response.data.elementsJson.factories;
    this.allCapabilities = response.data.elementsJson.config.capabilities;
  });
  axios.get('.......').then(response => {
    this.allCountries = response.data;
  });
 }
  })
  

</script>
```

Comment: The way you're using the setter for the computed properties doesn't make sense. What're you trying to do here? Your code is so minimal that I can't really understand your use of the computed property. It sounds like it should simply be in the components data instead.

Comment: You are right the getter and setter doesn't make sense. I updated my code example. I hope it is more clear. The computed property "filterFactories" calls some other function to filter my set of factories. And now I want to update/reset "filterFactories" with the new button which calls and ajax request.

Comment: If that's the case, you should be storing your data in `this.factories`, and then let `filterFactories` filter through your factories every time `this.factories` is updated. This is done automagically by Vue so you don't have to worry about that (in other words, `this.filterFactories` will react to changes in `this.factories` and perform filtering every time the latter is updated).

Comment: One of the problems is that your `axios.post` handler does not have its context bound to the Vue instance (and would be `window` by default), so `this.filterFactories` is incorrectly setting `window.filterFactories`. A simple solution is to use an arrow function to preserve the correct context: `axios.post(...).then(response => this.filterFactories = response)`.

Comment: thanks for you help. I tried your approach "window.filterFactories" but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Vue uses some magic for computed properties: it scans the function code and will automatically create watchers for the properties it finds within the code. This works well for simple situations but has failed many times for me with loops, map, reduce, etc.

I use multiple workarounds as needed, what is simplest to understand is this: create an artificial property which you reference in the computed prop and then update as needed:

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        updated: 0,
    },
    computed: {
        myComputed(): {
            // ...
            // just a reference to the prop
            this.updated;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        myAjax(): {
            // ...
            // modifying the prop will trigger update of myComputed
            this.updated++;
        },
    },
});
```

Of course you should use names more appropriate to the use cases you have, however i have instances where i just called this property "updateDummy" ;)

Comment: *'it scans the function code and will automatically create watchers for the properties it finds within the code'*. That isn't quite right, there is no scanning or code analysis. The function is just run and Vue keeps track of any reactive properties that get read while it is running. That's what all the `get`/`set` property rewriting is for, so that Vue knows every time a property is read. You shouldn't be having problems with loops, map, reduce, etc.. Problems tend to be caused either by asynchronous code or non-reactive property updates.